# How to enable/disable input field depending on checkbox with Reactstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

On the page I have with reactstrap, I have a checkbox and when this checkbox is checked, I would like the input field to be enabled and if it is unchecked then the input field disabled. How would I go abouts doing this? This is my current code:

```
import {
    Input,
    FormGroup,
    FormText,
    Form,
    Label,
    Button,
  } from "reactstrap";

function HelloWorld() {
   let mpinput;
      if ((e) => e.target.checked === true) {
        mpinput = <Input type="text" name="pmInput" id="pmInput"/>
      } else {
        mpinput = <Input type="text" name="pmInput" id="pmInput" disabled />
      }
   return (
   ...
   <FormGroup check>
       <Label check>
           <Input type="checkbox" id="mpCheckbox" onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.checked)} />
           <Label for="mpinput">Input Field</Label>
           {mpinput}
       </Label>
   </FormGroup>
   )
}
export default HelloWorld;
```

I know I have done something wrong since it is not working how I would like it to, and my guess is that its something to do with the 'if' statement or I am missing something. Sorry if this is a beginners question, I am still working my way through react. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use state to keep track of the check status

```
function HelloWorld() {
   const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = React.useState(false)

   return (
   ...
   <FormGroup check>
       <Label check>
           <Input type="checkbox" id="mpCheckbox" onChange={(e) => setIsChecked(e.target.checked)} />
           <Label for="mpinput">Input Field</Label>
           <Input type="text" name="pmInput" id="pmInput" disabled={isChecked} />
       </Label>
   </FormGroup>
   )
}
export default HelloWorld;
```

In your code the if has no access to the `e` variable, it is only defined in the scope of the `onChange` callback, you need to use it to set the state inside of that callback, then you are able to use the checked status somewhere else.

I moved the input on the return, but your `if` would also work with the `isChecked`

Comment: Thank you very much for the help